# Does having lots of regions create performance issues

Tags: views, theming

I am building a site in drupal 7. All the contents are created  using views.The themes structure is such that i have to use a lot of regions to display the blocks created by views. Its almost like one region for one block. Does having lot of regions impact performance. I could  avoid using regions if i print views using views_embed_view() function. But i think that is not recommended. You suggestions please.

Comment: What caching strategies are you using?

Comment: I don't think the number of regions is an issue. The number of blocks are.

Comment: If you are creating block views, they should be listed under disabled in `/admin/structure/block` So all you have to do is drag them up to the region you like.

Comment: @Mołot Page caching would be enabled and most of the blocks is  DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE

Comment: Explain why you need one region per view block and not one region for many blocks.